# CUDA: commands don't work after nvcc

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I am trying to compile a .cu program with nvcc and after every time I try and compile in Unix, my commands no longer work. I get an error:

'command': command not found.

Why is that? I have to logout/exit after each time I compile.

[EDIT]
I actually found that setting the path: setenv PATH /usr/local/cuda/bin 
causes the problem. Commands like: ls, pico, cd, etc. do not work. I can exit and logout

Comment: `nvcc` is probably defined as a function (or alias) in the current shell which is incorrectly resetting your `PATH`.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details. Do you do anything else? Which commands fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are deleting your path, you need to append to the PATH instead of overwriting it.

```
setenv PATH ${PATH}:/usr/local/cuda/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do `setenv PATH /usr/local/cuda/bin`  You want to do `setenv PATH $PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin`  or some variant of that like `setenv PATH $PATH":/usr/local/cuda/bin"`  When you do it your way, you are *replacing* your existing PATH definition, so you lose the command path to all those other commands.  Try `echo $PATH` to see what it looks like before you change it.  You want to *add to it*, not replace it.